Duckstation 8BitDo SN30 Pro Debian
I recently bought an 8BitDo SN30 Pro Wired USB controller.
I thought this would work with DuckStation, like my official Xbox controller did, on my debian system (once I installed some xbox driver).
It did not.
How do you get this SN30 Pro to work with debian 12 bookworm on DuckStation?
